# How to invoke EnumSet#(all|none)Of with a Class<?>?

Tags: java, generics, enumset

I need to invoke [EnumSet#nonOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#noneOf(java.lang.Class)) or [EnumSet#allOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf(java.lang.Class)) with an unknown type of class.

```java
    @Override
    public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
        final EnumSetOfAll annotation = parameterContext.getParameter().getAnnotation(EnumSetOfAll.class);
        final Class<?> value = annotation.value();
        if (!value.isEnum()) {
            throw new ParameterResolutionException("value(" + value + ") is not an enum");
        }

        // How can I return the result of EnumSet#(all|none)Of invoked with value?

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change the type of your annotation's `value()` to `Class<? extends Enum>`.

Now you can do:

```
final Class<? extends Enum> value = annotation.value();
```

Now this can be passed to `allOf` and `noneOf`:

```
EnumSet<?> set = EnumSet.allOf(value);
```